# JavaScript not working for more than two input fields in num lock numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've form  validation using JavaScript, I'm using this to allow only numbers on keyboard in input fields including numbers in top and num lock numbers. But this JavaScript only work for first input field, but I have several inputs fields how to adjust it?

**The Problem is related to num lock numbers in keyboard right side.**

In input second and third, num lock numbers not working. How to solve it?

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#inp1").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) != '-' && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      $("#errmsg1").html("* Input digits (0 - 9)").show().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("#inp2").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) != '-' && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      $("#errmsg2").html("* Input digits (0 - 9)").show().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("#inp3").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) != '-' && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      $("#errmsg3").html("* Input digits (0 - 9)").show().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#errmsg {
  color: red;
}

#errmsg2 {
  color: blue;
}

#errmsg3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp1" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg1"></span></p>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp2" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg2"></span></p>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp3" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg3"></span></p>
```

Comment: Why not change `<input type="text"` to `<input type="number"`?

Comment: You will find your answer here: [KeyEvents - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#Notes). Please read *special cases*.

Comment: because in the form fields, some of input fields have different targets that it can be used for number and text. that's why I used text but restricted to the numbers. the same form has other validation to check text as input if user click the form for different section.

Comment: You can check this to accept only numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `keypress` for first one but `keydown` for others. If you change second and third one to `keypress` too your problem will be solved. You can also optimize your code basically like this without changing too much thing. But there is better ways to optimize.

### Original Version

I added this after you said I need to use both events.

Keypress event treats `A` and `a` differently while keydown looks for only which button is pressed and treats `A` and `a` same. All you need is changing
`(e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)` to `(e.which < 96 || e.which > 105)` in keydown events.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inp1").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) != '-' && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
      $("#errmsg1").html("* Input digits (0 - 9)").show().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });
  $("#inp2").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) != '-' && (e.which < 96 || e.which > 105)) {
      $("#errmsg2").html("* Input digits (0 - 9)").show().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });
  $("#inp3").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(e.which) != '-' && (e.which < 96 || e.which > 105)) {
      $("#errmsg3").html("* Input digits (0 - 9)").show().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#errmsg {
  color: red;
}

#errmsg2 {
  color: blue;
}

#errmsg3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp1" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg1"></span></p>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp2" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg2"></span></p>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp3" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg3"></span></p>
```

### Smally Optimized Version

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //All ids seperated with commas(,) which means 'or'
  $("#inp1, #inp2, #inp3").each(function(i) {
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && String.fromCharCode(
          e.which) != '-' && (e.which < 48 || e.which >
          57)) {
        // i starts from zero but errmsg ids starts from 1 so we must use (i+1)
        $("#errmsg" + (i + 1)).html("* Input digits (0 - 9)").show()
          .delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#errmsg {
  color: red;
}

#errmsg2 {
  color: blue;
}

#errmsg3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp1" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg1"></span></p>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp2" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg2"></span></p>
Number : <input type="text" name="quantity" id="inp3" />&nbsp;<span id="errmsg3"></span></p>
```

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: But this is answer at the same time.

Comment: No. An answer is something that explains the issue and solution. This is a suggestion

Comment: _Avoid answering questions at comments_

Comment: Thanks for your pointing to the right section, but I'm looking for solution for both methods keypress and keydown.

Comment: Your Smally Optimized Version is perfect. Thanks and thumps up. :)

Comment: You can also change selector to `input[id*="inp"]` which means 'find inputs which id of them contains "inp"'.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful for you. This is for keydown event.

```
 $("#inp3").keydown(function (e) {         
       let code = e.keyCode - 48 * Math.floor(e.keyCode / 48);
       if (code != 8 && code != 0 && String.fromCharCode(code) != '-' && (code < 48 || code > 57)) {
            $("#errmsg3").html("* Input digits (0 - 9)").show().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
            return false;
       }
 });
```